# File in wromg format

Tags: c++, file, format

I have searched this site and all over on Google for an answer to this problem. I am trying to compile a simple GL program and whenever I compile I get the following error:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\GL/glew32.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: my guess is 64 bit program and you are trying to load a 32 bit lib

Comment: That's what I have read though I have no idea what so ever of how to fix that....

Comment: After reading your comment and research I tried linking the 64 bit libraries and getting the same error message

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have a Unix make file (the forward slash /glew32.lib) running on Microsoft using MinGW. ld -1 is the linkage editor complaining about a previous error. You might want to review the GLEW documentation: http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html and make sure the libraries are lined up for MinGW. You can make sure you have the right MinGW (32 bit or 64 bit) compiler here: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php

Comment: Thank you so much I will have to try that out